# Logic: is ( A && !(B || C)) || ( B || C ) the same as ( A || B || C )?

Tags: logic

I've encountered some obj-c code and I'm wondering if there's a way to simplify it:

```
#if ( A && !(B || C)) || ( B || C )
```

is this the same as?

```
#if ( A || B || C )
```

If not, is there another way to formulate it that would be easier to read?

[edit]
I tried the truth table before asking the question, but thought I had to be missing something because I doubted that Foundation.framework/Foundation.h would employ this more complex form.   Is there a good reason for it?

Here's the original code (from Foundation.h):

```
#if (TARGET_OS_MAC && !(TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED || TARGET_OS_IPHONE)) || (TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED || TARGET_OS_IPHONE)
```

Comment: why not just implement a little truth table with the outcomes and test it yourself? There's only 8 different inputs   |A=true, B=true, C=true | A=true, B=true. C=false | and so on and so forth. Compare the truth tables. If the outputs are the same, then your logic is equivalent.

Comment: Your parentheses in the header of the question are slightly different than in the question itself. If the header is correct, then the section "!(B || C) || (B || C)" can be replaced with "true", leaving you with "A && true", which is equivalent to just A. On the other hand, the question version seems to be missing one pair of parentheses, otherwise you have a syntax error.  Beyond that, I agree with the other posters, create the truth tables.

Comment: @Peter Perháč - thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes.  Like others said, you can truth table it.  The De Morgan rules can also help.

However, I think the best option is to use a [Karnaugh Map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_maps).  It takes a few minutes to learn, but Karnaugh Maps allow you to consistently find the most minimal expression for boolean logic.  Truth tables can verify a minimization, but they can't give it to you.

Here's how I got it:

First, the table layout:

```
         AB
     00   01   11   10
  0|    |    |    |    |
C 1|    |    |    |    |
```

Now, considering your equation, B || C will always cause a truth:

```
         AB
     00   01   11   10
  0|    |  T |  T |    |
C 1|  T |  T |  T |  T |
```

This leaves only two cases.  In either case, the right side evaluates to false.  For 000, the left side also evaluates to false (0 && !(whatever) is false).  For 100, 1 && !(0 ||| 0) evaluates to true.  Thus, the statement is true.  Filling in:

```
         AB
     00   01   11   10
  0|  F |  T |  T |  T |
C 1|  T |  T |  T |  T |
```

Now, we only need to "cover" all the truths.  "C" will cover the bottom row.  "B" will cover the middle square (of four values).  Thus, "B || C" covers all but the top right square.  Now, "A" will cover the right four-space square.  It's OK that this is redundant.  Thus, "A || B || C" covers all the true squares and omits the only false one.

Comment: This is a better answer than the question deserved, and educational to boot.

Answer (score 7):

Get pen + paper + try it, there are only 8 possible inputs

Comment: Naturally I tried that first. I reputed the code's source to be above this seemingly obscure formulation: OSX's Foundation.h.  Hence I doubted my scribblings.  But yes, +1 for your excellent first instinct.

Comment: I'm an experimental physicist - given the choice of doing maths or making measurements I go for the dumb solution

Comment: I am too, but which one is dumb and which one isn't depends on the experiment. ;)

Comment: @john - well the smart option is to do it the dumbest way first!

Answer (score 7):

```
A | B | C | (B || C) | (!(B || C)) | (A && !(B || C)) | (A && (!(B || C)) || (B || C) | (A || B || C)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
T | T | T |     T    |       F     |         F        |                 T             |         T      
T | T | F |     T    |       F     |         F        |                 T             |         T 
T | F | T |     T    |       F     |         F        |                 T             |         T 
T | F | F |     F    |       T     |         T        |                 T             |         T 
F | T | T |     T    |       F     |         F        |                 T             |         T 
F | T | F |     T    |       F     |         F        |                 T             |         T 
F | F | T |     T    |       F     |         F        |                 T             |         T 
F | F | F |     F    |       T     |         F        |                 F             |         F
```

Based on the last two columns, I would say yes.

Comment: @detunized, yeah I &&'ed the last two instead of ||'ed.  They are equal

Answer (score 7):

They are the same.  You can use [Truth Table Generator](http://turner.faculty.swau.edu/mathematics/materialslibrary/truth/) to test it.  Both these expressions give `false` only in one case, when `A`, `B` and `C` are `false`.

Comment: that's a clever link.  I'll share it with my math-teacher friends. +1

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is the same. Using De Morgan rules:

(A && !(B || C)) || (B || C) = (A && !B && !C) || (B || C).
So the second will be true when A = 1 and B, C = 0. If that is not the case the second part (B || C) will be true when B || C. So it is equal to the first.

Answer (score 1):

You could also say :

(A && !(B || C)) || (B || C) rewrites to (A && !W) || W (1)

(1) rewrites to (A && !W) || (A || !A || W) (2)

(2) rewrites (A && !W) || (A || W) || (!A || W) (3)

(3) rewrites (A && !W) || !(A && !W) || (A || W) (4)

(4) leads to A || W and then **A || B || C**

Comment: You could also say `A ^ (B || C)` no?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the two expressions are equivalent.  (I just wrote a couple of functions to test all eight possibilities.)