# Approaches to converting a table of possibilities into logical statements

Tags: sql, logic, business-logic

I'm not sure how to express this problem, so my apologies if it's already been addressed.

I have business rules summarized as a table of outputs given two inputs.  For each of five possible value on one axis, and each of five values on another axis, there is a single output.  There are ten distinct possibilities in these 25 cells, so it's not the case that each input pair has a unique output.

I have encoded these rules in TSQL with nested CASE statements, but it's hard to debug and modify.  In C# I might use an array literal.  I'm wondering if there's an academic topic which relates to converting logical rules to matrices and vice versa.

As an example, one could translate this trivial matrix:

```
   A  B  C
-- -- -- --
X  1  1  0
Y  0  1  0
```

...into rules like so:

```
if B OR (A and X) then 1 else 0
```

...or, in verbose SQL:

```
CASE WHEN FieldABC = 'B'                   THEN 1
     WHEN FieldABX = 'A' AND FieldXY = 'X' THEN 1
     ELSE 0
```

I'm looking for a good approach for larger matrices, especially one I can use in SQL (MS SQL 2K8, if it matters).  Any suggestions?  Is there a term for this type of translation, with which I should search?

Comment: I'm still not 100% clear on what you are asking, but have you considered the [CLR?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_CLR)

Comment: @wtjones: That's absolutely an option, though it entails some administrative overhead I'd like to avoid if possible.  What I'm looking for in this question is more abstract: what's an *approach* I can use to converting tabular logic into ANDs and ORs (or &&s and ||s).  For starters, is there a name for this kind of transformation?

Comment: I've been reading up on Karnaugh maps, by way of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763721/logic-is-a-b-c-b-c-the-same-as-a-b-c; it looks like it might be the right direction.  Opinions?

Comment: No, maybe not; these seem to be limited to answering a binary question.  My need is to provide one of several outputs based on different values for several inputs; assuming that the inputs are Boolean is reasonable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a lookup into a 5x5 grid of data. The inputs on axis and the output in each cell:

```
    Y=1 Y=2 Y=3 Y=4 Y=5
x=1  A   A   D   B   A
x=2  B   A   A   B   B
x=3  C   B   B   B   B
x=4  C   C   C   D   D
x=5  C   C   C   C   C
```

You can store this in a table of x,y,outvalue triplets and then just do a look up on that table.

```
SELECT OUTVALUE FROM BUSINESS_RULES WHERE X = @X and Y = @Y;
```

Comment: I was hoping for something rule-based, rather than a lookup table, as it's generally easier to read.  Still, this is a perfectly legit approach, and produces VERY compact SQL.  Fast, too.

Comment: Ok, [Karnaugh maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) illustrate a way to convert the grid to logical statements. Take one output at a time keeping in mind since it will be wrapped in a CASE statement any squares that already generated an output can be ignored from then on.